# Convert numpy array of array to dataframe of string

Tags: python, arrays, dataframe, numpy-ndarray

I am having trouble to convert my array of array to an array of string :

```
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])
```

I want to build a dataframe that would look like :

```
     "coordinate"
   0   '-1 -1'
   1   '-2 -1'
   2   '-3 -2'
   3   '1 1'
   4   '2 1'
   5   '3 2'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are a few ways you can do this -

#### With List comprehension

1. Convert X elements to string using str(i)
2. Iterate over each row with list comprehension, and join with space in between using `' '.join(i)`
3. Convert to a data frame with column name "coordinates"

```
data = [' '.join(str(i)) for i in X]
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['coordinates'])
print(df)
```

```
  coordinates
0       -1 -1
1       -2 -1
2       -3 -2
3         1 1
4         2 1
5         3 2
```

#### With Numpy

1. Convert X elements to string using `.astype(str)`
2. Then you can apply `' '.join()` over axis 1 to concatenate array
3. Convert to a data frame with column name "coordinates"

```
data = np.apply_along_axis(' '.join, 1, X.astype(str))
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['coordinates'])
print(df)
```

```
  coordinates
0       -1 -1
1       -2 -1
2       -3 -2
3         1 1
4         2 1
5         3 2
```

#### With Pandas

You can do this with pandas as well.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(X)
df = df[0].map(str)+' '+df[1].map(str)
df = pd.DataFrame(df, columns=['coordinates'])
print(df)
```

```
  coordinates
0       -1 -1
1       -2 -1
2       -3 -2
3         1 1
4         2 1
5         3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this in the following manner:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])

df = pd.DataFrame(columns=['coordinate'])

for index, item in enumerate(X):                                                                
    df.at[index, 'coordinate'] = ' '.join(item.astype(str))
```

Results in:

```
print(df)

coordinate
0      -1 -1
1      -2 -1
2      -3 -2
3        1 1
4        2 1
5        3 2
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use f-strings and list comprehension for example to do this task.
For example:

`X = np.array([[-1, -1], [-2, -1], [-3, -2], [1, 1], [2, 1], [3, 2]])`

`X_string = np.array([f"{i[0]} {i[1]}" for i in X])`

`pd.DataFrame(data=X_string, columns=["coordinates"])`

Output will be exactly the same as desired. But I think that this is not the best design for your task. If I were you I would likely split coordinates column into two separate (for example "lat" and "lon").